# multiple operations on spark dataframe columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a dataframe as shown below. The number of signals are more than 200, so there will be more than 200 columns in the dataframe.
I am not familiar with the calculations on multiple columns in scala.

```
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|id |        date|signal01|signal02|signal03|
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |3       |0       |
|050|2021-01-15  |null    |3       |0       |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |3       |0       |
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |3       |0       |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |null    |null    |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |3       |0       |
|051|2021-02-03  |1       |3       |0       |
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |3       |0       |
|052|2021-03-05  |2       |3       |null    |
|052|2021-03-06  |2       |null    |0       |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |5       |0       |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

The process I have to do on this dataframe is bit lenghty one as described below.

1. Split the dataframe with columns **id, date, signal01** and so on...more than 200 dataframes, one for each signal.

```
+---+------------+--------+
|id |        date|signal01|
+---+------------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |
|050|2021-01-15  |null    |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-02-03  |1       |
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |
|052|2021-03-05  |2       |
|052|2021-03-06  |2       |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |
+-------------------------+

+---+------------+--------+
|id |        date|signal02|
+---+------------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |3       |
|050|2021-01-15  |3       |
|050|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-01-14  |3       |
|051|2021-01-15  |null    |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-02-03  |3       |
|052|2021-03-03  |3       |
|052|2021-03-05  |3       |
|052|2021-03-06  |null    |
|052|2021-03-16  |5       |
+-------------------------+
```

2. Count of total signal per id to a count table as shown below.

```
counter table
+---+-----------------+-----------+
|id |signal01_total|signal02_total|
+---+--------------+--------------+
|050|51            |51            |
|051|58            |58            |
|052|61            |61            |
+---+--------------+--------------+
```

3. Remove the null and NaN records from the individual dataframes. (for all 200+ dataframes)

```
+---+------------+--------+
|id |        date|signal01|
+---+------------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-02-03  |1       |
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |
|052|2021-03-05  |2       |
|052|2021-03-06  |2       |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |
+-------------------------+

+---+------------+--------+
|id |        date|signal02|
+---+------------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |3       |
|050|2021-01-15  |3       |
|050|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-01-14  |3       |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-02-03  |3       |
|052|2021-03-03  |3       |
|052|2021-03-05  |3       |
|052|2021-03-16  |5       |
+-------------------------+
```

4. Take count of these signals tables without null record and add column to counter table as shown below.

```
counter table
+---+--------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|id |signal01_total|signal01_without_NaN|signal02_total|signal02_without_NaN|
+---+--------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|050|51            |50                  |51            |50                  |
|051|58            |56                  |58            |55                  |
|052|61            |60                  |61            |59                  |
+---+--------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

5. On the null records removed dataframes for signals, add new column for cummax value of signal.

```
+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|id |        date|signal01|signal01_cummax|
+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |1              |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |1              |
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |1              |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |2              |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |3              |
|051|2021-02-03  |1       |3              |
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |1              |
|052|2021-03-05  |2       |2              |
|052|2021-03-06  |2       |2              |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |3              |
+-------------------------+---------------+

+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|id |        date|signal02|signal02_cummax|
+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|050|2021-01-14  |3       |3              |
|050|2021-01-15  |3       |3              |
|050|2021-02-02  |3       |3              |
|051|2021-01-14  |3       |3              |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |3              |
|051|2021-02-03  |3       |3              |
|052|2021-03-03  |3       |3              |
|052|2021-03-05  |3       |3              |
|052|2021-03-16  |5       |5              |
+-------------------------+---------------+
```

6. Drop the records which are having **signal01 < signal01_cummax** and drop **signal_cummax** column

```
+---+------------+--------+
|id |        date|signal01|
+---+------------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |
|052|2021-03-05  |2       |
|052|2021-03-06  |2       |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |
+-------------------------+

+---+------------+--------+
|id |        date|signal02|
+---+------------+--------+
|050|2021-01-14  |3       |
|050|2021-01-15  |3       |
|050|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-01-14  |3       |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |
|051|2021-02-03  |3       |
|052|2021-03-03  |3       |
|052|2021-03-05  |3       |
|052|2021-03-16  |5       |
+-------------------------+
```

7. Take count of this records per ID and add to count table.

```
counter table
+---+--------------+--------------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------+------------------------+
|id |signal01_total|signal01_without_NaN|signal01_without_Invalid|signal02_total|signal02_without_NaN|signal02_without_Invalid|
+---+--------------+--------------------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------+------------------------+
|050|51            |50                  |49                      |   51         |50                  |48                      |
|051|58            |56                  |55                      |   58         |55                  |53                      |
|052|61            |60                  |60                      |   61         |59                  |59                      |
+---+--------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------+--------------------+------------------------+
```

8. On the signals table add a column named signal_difference with first diff column value as 0 as shown below.

```
+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|id |        date|signal01|signal01_diff  |
+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |0              |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |0              |
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |0              |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |1              |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |1              |
|051|2021-02-03  |3       |0              |
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |0              |
|052|2021-03-05  |2       |1              |
|052|2021-03-06  |2       |0              |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |1              |
+-------------------------+---------------+

+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|id |        date|signal02|signal02_diff  |
+---+------------+--------+---------------+
|050|2021-01-14  |3       |0              |
|050|2021-01-15  |3       |0              |
|050|2021-02-02  |3       |0              |
|051|2021-01-14  |3       |0              |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |0              |
|051|2021-02-03  |3       |0              |
|052|2021-03-03  |3       |0              |
|052|2021-03-05  |3       |0              |
|052|2021-03-16  |5       |2              |
+-------------------------+---------------+
```

9. Finally Union all these signal tables to form a single dataframe with number of columns = 2* no of signals.

```
+---+------------+--------+---------------+--------+---------------+
|id |        date|signal01|signal01_diff  |signal02|signal02_diff  |
+---+------------+--------+---------------+--------+---------------+
|050|2021-01-14  |1       |0              |3       |0              |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |0              |3       |0              |
|050|2021-02-02  |1       |0              |null    |null           |
|051|2021-01-14  |1       |0              |3       |0              |
|051|2021-01-15  |2       |1              |3       |0              |
|051|2021-02-02  |3       |1              |3       |0              |
|051|2021-02-03  |3       |0              |3       |0              |
|052|2021-03-03  |1       |0              |3       |0              |
|052|2021-03-05  |2       |1              |3       |0              |
|052|2021-03-06  |null    |null           |5       |2              |
|052|2021-03-16  |3       |1              |5       |2              |
+-------------------------+---------------+--------+---------------+
```

Instead of seperating each signal column as a seperate dataframe, by keeping all in a single initial dataframe, could we achieve this?

I have tried and able to get the second count of valid records, but not able to proceed from deleting the null/NaN records and applying cummmax value.

Is there any way to proceed? Any idea how to use window,grp,agg functions effectively to avoid creating multiple dataframes.

Any lead much appreciated.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken : Any idea how to implement this?